# Is this the right blender download?

Tags: installation

So I had downloaded blender today (so I am a newbie, so apologies if I am saying something stupid ) and for those working on MacOS would know that when you download new software the system normally tells you this app was downloaded from the internet do you want to open it and so on. One thing weird though was the site shown for the download was "ftp.nluug.nl" and not blender.org, I am not being stupid right, I have downloaded the correct app right?

Thank you

Jay

Comment: Seems you are new to IOS as well... That's a usual warning, just make sure you're downloading from https://www.blender.org/download/ Also I recommend take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Ok cool, yh I am familiar that its the usual warning just expected to see blender.org that's all, I downloaded it from blender but just wanted double check.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLUUG

Comment: Hey Jay, I edited your title back to the original.  We typically don't put that in the title of the question, users can see if a question has an accepted answer by the solid green box around the number of answers in the search.  Since you've accepted an answer, this question is good to go.

Comment: @AllenSimpson, 
Thank you for correcting the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have downloaded Blender from one of the mirror servers. They are used to ensure availability in case Blender's servers aren't reachable or the download speed is too slow.

In order to check if your copy is genuine, you can check if the SHA256 hash of the `*.dmg` file matches the official release. Additionally, the official Blender releases are signed. GateKeeper should validate the signature before execution or you can manually validate it by running codesign from the terminal (change the path to match the actual location):

```
codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 /path/to/blender.app
```

The releases hosted on Blender's website can be found at the following URL: https://download.blender.org/release/

The SHA256 hashes for Blender 2.93.1 can be found in the file `blender-2.93.1.sha256` [here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.93/).

Comment: Thank you, for helping out .

Comment: Was suffering from crazy slow download speeds, but then went to the link you shared (https://download.blender.org/release/), browsed to the one I wanted and got the whole 159MB in 2 minutes :D thankyou!